Stroboscopic sampling of a random process
Consider a random process that is an alternation of two phases, labeled "0" and "1".
The duration of phase events are governed by the exponential distributions, $Exp_{\lambda_0}(\tau)$ and $Exp_{\lambda_1}(\tau)$ respectively. I generate a semi-infinite realization of the process and then move over it with a window of the length $T$ so the realization is chopped into pieces of length $T$. Every piece starts with a certain phase, either "0" or "1", and the durations of these first events are described by pdfs $p_0(\tau)$ and $p_1(\tau)$, respectively.
What are $p_0(\tau)$ and $p_1(\tau)$? My intuition says that they are $Exp_{\lambda_0}(\tau)$ and $Exp_{\lambda_1}(\tau)$. Is this true? If it is - how to prove it?
What about the pdfs of the last pieces? My intuition says that they are the same exponential distributions but now truncated at $\tau = T$, with a peak  at $\tau=T$ into which the remaining part, $Exp(\tau >T)$, is integrated in. Is it true? If yes - how to prove it?

I am not following what you mean by "... and the durations of these pieces are described by" in the end of the second paragraph. If I understood correctly, the length of each piece is exactly $T$ by your construction. Are you referring to the duration of the first phase appearing in the given piece?

Maybe it is also good to use symbols for clarification. I guess you begin with a continuous-time Markov chain $(X(t)){t\in[0,\infty)}$ on the state space ${0,1}$ and with transition rates given by $\lambda{0\to1}=\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_{1\to 0}=\lambda_1$, and then you are looking at the pieces $(X(t))_{t\in[(k-1)T, kT]}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$. Then you are interested in the duration of the first/last phase in each of these pieces. Is this correct?

@Sangchul Lee "Are you referring to the duration of the first phase appearing in the given piece?" Yes, exactly

@Sangchul Lee "Is this correct?" Yes, thank you. It is a precise formulation of the question.
